# Role Openshift : Allow to rollback a previous version of a deployment without having the right to change it

Tags: openshift

I am looking for a solution to allow a user to rollback a previous version of a deployment without having the right to modify the deployment (images, environment variables, strategy,...).

I'm trying to create a role for developers who will only use CICD Pipelines to deploy a new version but I would like them to be able to go back if necessary.

Currently the role in particular:

```
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  - apps.openshift.io
  attributeRestrictions: null
  resources:
  - deploymentconfigs
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  - apps.openshift.io
  attributeRestrictions: null
  resources:
  - deploymentconfigs/scale
  verbs:
  - create
  - delete
  - deletecollection
  - get
  - list
  - patch
  - update
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  - apps.openshift.io
  attributeRestrictions: null
  resources:
  - deploymentconfigrollbacks
  - deploymentconfigs/instantiate
  - deploymentconfigs/rollback
  verbs:
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  - apps.openshift.io
  attributeRestrictions: null
  resources:
  - deploymentconfigs/log
  - deploymentconfigs/status
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

I get the following error :

```
$ oc rollback DC_NAME --to-version=19
Error from server (Forbidden): deploymentconfigs.apps.openshift.io "DC_NAME" is forbidden: User "foo" cannot update deploymentconfigs.apps.openshift.io in the namespace "NAMESPACE_NAME": User "foo" cannot update deploymentconfigs.apps.openshift.io in project "NAMESPACE_NAME"
```

Or

```
$ oc rollout undo dc DC_NAME --to-revision=19
Error from server (Forbidden): deploymentconfigs.apps.openshift.io "DC_NAME" is forbidden: User "foo" cannot update deploymentconfigs.apps.openshift.io in the namespace "NAMESPACE_NAME": User "foo" cannot update deploymentconfigs.apps.openshift.io in project "NAMESPACE_NAME"
```

If I add the verb "update" to the resource "deploymentconfigs", I don't have any errors but the developer can modify the deployment.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which access level the user logged in Openshift has?

First you need to consult that with the command bellow:

```
oc get rolebindings | grep your-username
```

You need a user with roles levels like **edit** or **admin** to be able run the rollback command.